# How do I add an id attribute in HTML div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I got failed to create the id on that button clicked event. Is this because of the event on that button? Is there any way to create an id on the same button clicked?
Here is my JavaScript function. It doesn't work as expected for me.

```
<div class="DivButton" style="" onclick="divClick()"></div>
function divClick()
{
    $(this).attr("id") =="Active";     
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Ids within the document should be unique, you can't have the same id value in multiple elements.

Comment: Because you compare (when using `==`) attribute ID with `Active`. Use it like this: `$(this).attr('id', 'Active')`

Comment: @Justinas I had tried this code but still not working

Comment: Use = not == and id is unique for one button

Comment: try thi `setAttribute(‘id’,‘active’);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('DivButton');
btn.setAttribute("id","Active");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers.

If you only *add* an id to elements, you'll end up with duplicate id's, which is not allowed in html. Better use an .active css-class.

The snippet uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains("DivButton")) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".DivButton")
      .forEach( bttn => bttn.classList.remove("active") );
    return evt.target.classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

```css
.DivButton {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 125px;l
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 0.3rem;
}

.active {
  color: red;
  background-color: #FFFFC0;
}
```

```html
<div class="DivButton active">a</div>
<div class="DivButton">b</div>
<div class="DivButton">c</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` into `divClick` function.

```js
function divClick(e){
   e.id = "Active";
   console.log(e);    
}
```

```html
<div class="DivButton" style="" onclick="divClick(this)">a</div>
<div class="DivButton" style="" onclick="divClick(this)">b</div>
<div class="DivButton" style="" onclick="divClick(this)">c</div>
```

Comment: I had tried this but i got error I don`t know why

Comment: <div class="DivButton" style="" onclick="divClick(hello, 1, 1 , this)">a</div> can you explain with this i want to try this out

Comment: @rabinadhikari what error you are getting ?

Comment: Menu01.aspx:145 Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (Menu01.aspx:145)

Comment: Have added one parameter in function like `divClick(e)` ?

Comment: I am talking about `function divClick(e){}`. Please show me your javascript code.

Comment: this is my jascript function function divClick(url, authorityPasswordFlag, logFlag, e)
{

Answer (score 0):

Try this html code

```
<div class="DivButton" style="" onclick="divClick(this)">Button1</div>
<div class="DivButton" style="" onclick="divClick(this)">Button2</div>
<div class="DivButton" style="" onclick="divClick(this)">Button3</div>
```

Javascript code
id should be unique

```
<script>
function divClick(e){
 e.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);   
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Comment: trye this function divClick(e){
            if (typeof variable === 'undefined') {
                e.id = 'id'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); 
                console.log(e.id); 
         } 
         }

Comment: This is my function name function divClick(url, authorityPasswordFlag, logFlag, e)
{} how do i define e

Comment: in your function if (typeof e === 'undefined') { // your code here}

Comment: now i got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

Comment: @rabinadhikari   e = e.srcElement;
                           e.id = 'id'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'srcElement' of undefined I got this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231778/discussion-between-marwen-jaffel-and-rabin-adhikari).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check if the `id` active exists and remove it if it does so it can be added to the new button.

```js
function divClick(e,idToAdd){
   if(document.querySelector('#active')){
    document.querySelector('#active').removeAttribute('id');
   }

   e.id = 'active';
 
}
```

```css
.DivButton {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem 3rem;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="DivButton" style="" onclick="divClick(this)">a</div>
<div class="DivButton" style="" onclick="divClick(this)">b</div>
<div class="DivButton" style="" onclick="divClick(this)">c</div>
```